# Could anyone explain this code to me？Leetcode #180

Tags: mysql

```
select distinct Num as ConsecutiveNums
from (
  select Num, 
    case 
      when @prev = Num then @count := @count + 1
      when (@prev := Num) is not null then @count := 1
    end as CNT
  from Logs, (select @prev := null,@count := null) as t
) as temp
where temp.CNT >= 3
```

I found this in
https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/consecutive-numbers/comments/

It is really difficult to understand, especially this sentence

```
(select @prev := null,@count := null) as t
```

Why can variable declaration be put there?

Answer (score 1):

> But it works in leetcode

Yes. This code is syntactically correct, so it does not produce errors. But it is not deterministic -- two executions of it can return different outputs whereas source data is the same. Forget this code. It is non-deterministic - i.e. it is wrong.

The code is processing order-dependent see [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4aae1cf7541635b87833eee99cbfa8e6).  But `ORDER BY` clause is absent - so the query is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the comma between From logs and the decalration port is a comma, which indicates a cross join.

For the algorithm to work, you need to declare the user defined variables @count and @num.

you can do this before you start the select or like in your case a cross joined SELECT.

In both cases the @count and @num exist and can be used by the query.

The rest is simple the query starts by the first row and goes then row for row.

the user defined variabes are set by the previous row or by the initialisation described before.

and the cross join does overwrite the variables or else the alghorithm wouldn't work.

Update:

This will increase the counter if the previous number is the same as before

```
when @prev = Num then @count := @count + 1
```

If the number isn't the same you reset the counter, and at the same time you give @prev the current Number in Num (including NULL)

```
 when (@prev := Num) is not null then @count := 1
```

This also includes that NULL values in the column Num don't count as new number or that it will increase the counter as in the next round the first case don't finds equality